# Can I work remotely for my US employer while on a Tier 4 visa in the UK?

Tags: visas, work, taxes

I’m an American, and I’m going to the UK on a tier 4 student visa. Under this visa, I’m allowed to work 20 hours/week with a UK employer. I must file taxes in both the US and the UK each year that I am there.

My American employer has offered to let me work remotely while I’m overseas, but I don’t anticipate them sending enough work to cover all of my expenses. Am I able to work both a part time UK job as well as work remotely for my American employer?

Answer (score 2):

The UK government's document explaining the Tier 4 student visa (application, documents required, and terms) is located [here](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/727420/T4_Migrant_Guidance_JULY_2018_FINAL.pdf).

You'll see in Section 311 *et seq* that the hours of employment and types of work are limited. I don't see anything in this document that would limit your work to only a UK employer, but the Tier 4 visa does appear to limit your total work hours.